# Split a string into arrays of string without a delimiter in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, split

Need to split a string into array of strings. Problem is that i havent delimiters.
For example: if i have 0970909547091000000089942200 and i need to split into array of strings and know that firs string have 3 digits, second string have 7 digits, third string have 2 digits and the like. I search, but anywhere is answer with any delimiters.

Comment: Why not just create some new fixed size arrays and manually copy the data in?

Comment: this is a row from db, i have a lot of rows in file and need to split this string into array of string( as host variable) and insert all rows in db. i know how to insert and other processing with bd, question is how to split string

Answer (score 1):

you just have to do it the hard way.

```
char first[4];
char second[8];
...
memcpy(first,str,3);
first[3] = 0;
memcpy(second, str + 3, 7);
second[7] = 0;
...
```

Comment: if i have 1000 strings like this in file? do it for each string in a loop? each string is split in the same mode.